# Why Django unique constraints did not work?

Tags: python, django

I've added UniqueConstraint into the constraints array in the Meta class which is a subclass of User table.

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
...
    class Meta:
         verbose_name = _("account")
        verbose_name_plural = _("accounts")
        indexes = [
            models.Index(name="email_index", fields=["email"])
        ]
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(name="check_birth_date", check=Q(birth_date__lt=f"{datetime.date.today()}")),
            models.CheckConstraint(name="check_phone_number", check=Q(phone_number__regex=r"^09(1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9])[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}$")),
            models.UniqueConstraint(name="username_email_unique", fields=["username", "email"])
        ]
```

My expectation was that prevent user to enter username and email with same value, But actually did not work and user can do it without getting the IntegrityError
Moreover, I'm using Postgresql

Comment: You’ve made the *combination* of username and email unique; that still allows duplicate usernames and emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My expectation was that prevent user to enter username and email with same value.

**No**: if you specify two or more fields, it means that the *combination* of these fields should be unique. In other words if there is a user *A* and a user *B*, it will only reject creating *B* if *both* the `.username` and the `.email` are the same.

You need to make the two fields individually unique. You can do that with the [**`unique=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique):

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    # …
```

Or if you want to do that through the constraints, you make two `UniqueConstraint`s, each for one field:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    # …
    class Meta:
        # …
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(name="check_birth_date", check=Q(birth_date__lt=f"{datetime.date.today()}")),
            models.CheckConstraint(name="check_phone_number", check=Q(phone_number__regex=r"^09(1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9])[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}$")),
            models.UniqueConstraint(name="username_unique", fields=["username"]),
            models.UniqueConstraint(name="email_unique", fields=["email"])
        ]
```

If you want to prevent that you enter the *same* value for both the `username` and the `email` field for each record, you need to add an extra [**`CheckConstraint`** constraint [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint):

```
from django.db.models import F, Q

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    # …
    class Meta:
        # …
        constraints = [
            # …
            models.CheckConstraint(check=~Q(username=F('email')), name='username_email_unique')
        ]
```

Comment: I think I could not say mine presume correctly.
I want to prevent user to creates an account with same value in username and email field. Look at this query:
```

Comment: ```
User.objects.create(email="same@gmail.com", username="same@gmail.com")
# prevent this
```

Comment: @NimaZ: ah but that is something different, that means for the *same* record the two can not be the same.

Comment: So how can I do it?

Comment: @NIMAZ: with a `CheckConstraint`, see update.

Comment: @NIMAZ: see (updated) andwer (previous update had some typos).